# Some counterexamples on measurable function about continuity and discontinuity.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

1. By Lusin, in finite measure, a measurable function is almost continuous, i.e., except small measure, the function is continuous.
   What if we remove the condition 'finite measure'? 
   Is there a measurable function defined on infinite measure which has a positive measure of discontinuity?
2. Consider the function $$f\ \colon\ 
   x\longmapsto\begin{cases}
   1&\text{if $x \in \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$}\\
   0&\text{if $x \in [0,1]\backslash \mathbb{Q}$}
   \end{cases}.$$ 
   To apply Lusin theorem here, choose $\mathbb{Q}^c \cap [0,1]$ as a small measurable set. Then is the function refined on $\mathbb{Q}$ continuous? How can we define the continuity on the function? (Guess: sequentially?)

Comment: I think you're confusing Egorov's theorem with Lusin's theorem.

Comment: @carmichael561 Oh thanks Ill revise it now!!